# Correct HTTP Status Code to be returned with OAuth Authorization Code grant type

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-codes

A new website I'm working has the following components:

- AngularJS/HTML5 Front-End
- Web API Back-End that supports Front-End
- OAuth Server - Authenticates user and provides tokens

The workflow for an unauthenticated user:

1. Views Front-End, which calls Web API to determine if authenticated
2. If not authenticated the user is redirected to OAuth Server
3. After successful authentication, the browser is redirected back to website with Auth Code
4. Auth Code is sent to Web API
5. Web API logic requests Access Token from OAuth server
6. A cookie is used to associate the token to the user
7. Additional requests send the cookie, which is used to authorize the user.

My question is what should I send for the HTTP Status Code for Step 1? Normally you send 401 for not unauthorized, but that is if you are using HTTP Authentication. Since the authentication is handled by a different server, that wouldn't make sense. 403 doesn't seem correct either because it implies a that the status will not change.

Should I just use a generic 400 or a custom 400.X code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is nothing wrong with sending `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` as a response in your case, a much better alternative would be to send `HTTP 302 Found`, which would imply that when the user was trying to access the front-end view, the applicable resource in this case (OAuth Server Url) was found somewhere else.

You can mention the OAuth Server Url in the `Location` header of the response, so the client would redirect the unauthenticated user to the intended location.

```
HTTP 302 Found
Location: https://oath-server-url.com
```

Comment: I like this approach, this way the client doesn't need to maintain the OAuth server URI. Why do recommend a 302 opposed to a 303?

Comment: I chose 302 as both your requests (original and redirected) are following the same method (GET). If you were changing from any other method to GET, you can use 303 in that case.

Comment: if we make a request using the POST method, a 302 redirect will return us to the get method. To avoid this, you can use `HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307